# Trying to junit test a function using mockito which needs to call another function of same class, getting org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: null

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Let's say I have 2 function like this: (I don't want to share the actual code, it's pretty huge)

```
public class EmailService{

    String addressList1 = "test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com";
    public String[] getAddressList(String addressList){
        return addressList.split(",");
    }
    public int getNumber(){
        for (String address : getAddressList(addressList1))
        {
            if (address.equals("test1@gmail.com")){return 1;}
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I tried this for testing the getNumber() function:

```
EmailService emailService1 = new EmailService();
EmailService emailService2 = Mockito.spy(emailService1);
String deliveryAddress = "test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com";       
doReturn(deliveryAddress.split(",")).when(emailService2).getAddressList(deliveryAddress);

assertEquals(EmailService2.getNumber(), 1);
```

But I'm getting:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: null

Comment: Well, I can see two compilation errors in the code that you've shown. It's hard to comment on why your code does what it does, if I have to guess at what your REAL code looks like.  In particular, what will `getNumber` return if the email address you're looking for is not found?  If it's null (which would mean that the return type is something other than `int`), then you'd get the error you've described.  But please don't make me guess at what your code MIGHT look like.

Comment: when I run debugging, I see the exception happens when the code try to loop through the addressList, my guess is that even though I'm mocking the getAddressList function. getNumber function doesn't have a list to loop through.

Comment: Where does `addressList1` come from?

Comment: @Lesiak it's a variable I have in the same class. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this.

Since addressList1 was a local variable, I had to set the value for this, before I call the getNumber function.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(emailService2, "addressList1","test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).